# TinyMCE wrap element with another one (the new one)

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

I am creating plugin for TinyMCE and I need to wrap existing elem (node) with new one.

For example, if I have paragraph:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

after command I need:

```
<div id="someid"><p>hello</p></div>
```

I tried below but it doesn;t wrap paragraphs, only theirs body, for example:

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',true,'<div id="someid">{$selection}</div>')
```

creates:

```
<p><div id="someid">hello</div></p>
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

**Update:**

Finaly I decided to use below construction (no jQuery):

```
// Get instance of the editor       
var ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor;

// we are collecting <p> or other default tag to cover it       
var node = tinyMCEPopup.editor.selection.getNode();

// create new dom objects   
var newNode =  ed.dom.create('div', {'class' : 'accordionContent'}); 
var newHNode =  ed.dom.create('h2', {'class' : 'accordionTitle'},document.forms[0].title.value);

// dom modifications
ed.dom.add(node.parentNode, newHNode);
ed.dom.add(node.parentNode, newNode);
newNode.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to use jQuery in your application there is a [wrap() function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/). If you had

```
<div id="someid">hello</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
$('#someid').wrap('<p />')
```

Gives you:

```
<p><div id="someid">hello</div></p>
```

Update:

Have read your question again and I think you may need [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) instead.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for (I think dependency on jQuery in TinyMCE plugin is not a good pattern) , but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I thought that would probably be the case - you could download the jQuery library and examine the WrapInner() method, then use that code to work from to write your own method using vanilla JavaScript. - Sorry just seen your update - looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but for future reference

```
var ed = tinymce.get("editorId");
$(ed.selection.getNode()).wrap("<div id='someid' />");
```